# Field Mappings control doesn't show the Add Input Field in the context menu of a Python Toolbox

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python-toolbox, field-mapping

I’m trying to build a *Python Toolbox* which uses a *Field Mappings* control (*GPFieldMapping* parameter). For some reason I don’t manage to get the same behaviour of the *Field Mappings* control as in the standard geoprocessing tools: *Append*, *Merge* …. On my tool, the context menu doesn’t show the *Add Input Field* command as it does in the *Append* tool (see print screen below). Any clues of why this might happen?

[image: Add Input Field in Append tool]
[image: No Add Input Field in Append tool]

Please find below my code:

```py
import arcpy

class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of the
        .pyt file)."""
        self.label = "Toolbox"
        self.alias = ""

        # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
        self.tools = [TestFieldMappings]


class TestFieldMappings(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
        self.label = "Test Field Mappings"
        self.description = ""
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """Define parameter definitions"""
        prm_base_feature = arcpy.Parameter(displayName = 'Base Feature Class',
                                           name = 'BaseFeatureClass',
                                           datatype = 'DETable',
                                           parameterType = 'Required',
                                           direction = 'Input')

        prm_test_feature = arcpy.Parameter(displayName = 'Test Feature Class',
                                           name = 'TestFeatureClass',
                                           datatype = 'DETable',
                                           parameterType = 'Required',
                                           direction = 'Input')

        prm_field_mappings = arcpy.Parameter(displayName = 'Field Mappings',
                                              name = 'FieldMappings',
                                              datatype = 'GPFieldMapping',
                                              parameterType = 'Optional',
                                              direction = 'Input')


        params = [prm_base_feature,
                  prm_test_feature,
                  prm_field_mappings]        
        # return parameters array          
        return params

    def isLicensed(self):
        """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
        return True

    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
        validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
        has been changed."""

        if parameters[0].altered and parameters[1].altered:
            if not (parameters[0].hasBeenValidated and parameters[1].hasBeenValidated):

                tmp_fms = arcpy.FieldMappings()  # Create empty FieldMappings object

                base_fields = [f for f in arcpy.ListFields(parameters[0].valueAsText) \
                                if f.type not in ['Geometry', 'Raster']]
                test_fields = [f for f in arcpy.ListFields(parameters[1].valueAsText)
                                if f.type not in ['Geometry', 'Raster']]            

                # loop base fields                
                for f in base_fields:
                    tmp_fm = arcpy.FieldMap()
                    tmp_fm.outputField = f

                    # loop test fields
                    for g in test_fields:

                        # if name matches, add the input field
                        if f.name == g.name:
                            tmp_fm.addInputField(parameters[1].valueAsText, g.name)

                    # add the field map
                    tmp_fms.addFieldMap(tmp_fm)
                parameters[2].value = tmp_fms.exportToString() 

        return

    def updateMessages(self, parameters):
        """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
        parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
        return

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        """The source code of the tool."""
        return
```

Notes:
I managed to make the Add Input Field show on my tool by using the initializing script of the Field Mappings in the getParameterInfo routine. This is of no use as I want the Field Mappings to be updated each time the input is changed